# Type-declaration character error -- MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I keep getting the "type-declaration character" error when I try to compile my code, but I don't understand why.

Here's the code (paraphrased):

```
Private Sub cboTest_AfterUpdate()

'( some code )

Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long

lngLen = Len(strWhere - 5)

strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

'( some code )

End Sub
```

The .accdb file that I'm working on is approximately 7000 KB, it has compiled several times prior to now, but for some reason every iteration of this is giving me problems. Any idea what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance,

J

Comment: In Access 2010 I get a different compile error for the line `lngLen = Len(strWhere - 5)`: "Variable required - can't assign to this expression". Do you actually mean `lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs here and dosn't fail for short strings:

```
Private Sub cboTest_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim lngLen As Long

    lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5        
    If lngLen >= 0 Then
        strWhere = Left(strWhere, lngLen)
    End If

    '( some code )

End Sub
```